# Label arrows on DataPoint C# chart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, datapoint

How do I change the color of these arrows? I'm developing a feature to highlight selected elements and the other others show in a light gray color, but can't find how to change the color of the arrow

```
chart1.Series[line_name].Color = Color.LightGrey;  // color of the lines

point.Color                    = Color.LightGray;  // color of the dots
point.LabelForeColor           = Color.LightGray;  // color of the text labels
```

any ideas?

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCwdj.png)

Comment: Can you show how you create the arrows in the 1st place?

Comment: I don't! They simply appear when there are too many DataPoint elements close together. When I zoom in, they spread out and the arrows disappear, and only the label text is shown, next to the point.

Comment: At least tell us which ChartType you use!

Comment: it's a Point chart!

Comment: Ok,. I did a few tests but I'm afraid there is no way to make those callout lines anything but black. There are [custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd456764(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) that sound promising but they won't work here,,

Comment: thank you, will have a look at this custom properties, otherwise I'll probably have to manually add a text on the chart close to the points, using XY values, then I'll be able to change color, but it's not the most elegant solution

Comment: Well why not change the points or use markers? They can be colored and sized easily..

Comment: Found how:

`chart1.Series["Series1"].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineColor = Color.LightGreen;`

this sets the color for all DataPoint elements in the Chart Series

Comment: I'll try to find a way to change the color of every DataPoint element, but they don't have the SmartLabelStyle property.

Comment: to eliminate those arrows you can do the following, but the chart could get messy if you have a lot of data:


`chart1.Series["Series1"].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = true;`